# Is there a physical interpretation of Poincaré duality?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, differential-geometry, field-theory, supersymmetry, topological-field-theory

Is there a known interpretation of [Poincaré duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_duality) in terms of a physical equivalence between (maybe topological) sectors of different (probably susy) quantum field theories?

Edit/update :

If on a manifold $M$ can be defined an N=2 superconformal field theory (for example a susy non linear $\sigma$-model with target $M$ a Calabi-Yau) then there is an physical interpretation of Poincaré duality as the *charge conjugation invariance of the Ramond vacuum*. This comes about by ignoring the higher modes of the string (propagating in a background from wich the sigma model comes from, which implis a large volume limit of the manifold), making the chiral ring of the superconformal theory isomorphic to Dolbeaut cohomology of the manifold.

Source: Lerche, W., Vafa, C., & Warner, N. P. (1989). Chiral rings in N = 2 superconformal theories. Nuclear Physics B, 324(2), 427–474. doi:10.1016/0550-3213(89)90474-4

It would be nice to extend this results, or to see reference for current state of the matter.

Comment: for starters, it plays an important role in (e.g. introducing gauge fields for) [higher form symmetries](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5148).